# Dual axis using percentage and absolute value to same serie in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need use a percentage and absolute value of the axis Y from the one serie.

There is some example in highchart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes but it's using two different series. I need, for example, value in axis Y until 1000 and in the other axis Y show the percentage to the item serie.

Comment: I think I know what you are asking but I am unclear on a few things. How would you mark what point is what percentage of the total? Can it a value be negative? If so, what percentage would that be? Is this category based or time-based? Do you have an example of your expected output? What does your data look like?

Comment: @wergeld I think I have the same question and will try to explain my situation. Basically I want a column chart that has two values associated with the y data. One is the number and the other is the percentage. These numbers I will pass into the chart, but I'm not sure how to display both.

Comment: @Squazic Create 2 series - 1 is the value and 2 is the percentage. Send the series 1 to primary y-axis and series 2 to secondary 7-axis. How you split the value and percentage out from the main data set is dependent on how you are formatting your data. I would post a new question with more details for me to look at.

Comment: @Squazic check answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a second Y-axis and link it to the first (0th) using the **[`xAxis.linkedTo`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.linkedTo)** property. Then in the label formatter of the second axis, to the calculations to get the percentage.

```
yAxis:[{            
    },
    {
        labels:{
            formatter:function(){
                var max=this.axis.linkedParent.dataMax,
                    min=this.axis.linkedParent.dataMin,
                    range=max-min;                       
                return ((this.value-min)/(range)*100) + ' %';
            }
        },
        linkedTo:0,
        opposite:true
    }
]
```

**[Dual axes | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/JBdLw/)**